# Steinberg Group  as  a  Lattice  in a  lie  group 

Tags: gr.group-theory, tag-removed, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Given  an integral  domain $R$,  the  Steinberg  group $St_n(R)$  is  the   group  given  by  generators
$e_{pq}(\lambda) := \mathbf{1} + a_{pq}(\lambda)$,
 $p\neq q$, $1\leq p,q \leq n$

Subject  to the  relations
$$\begin{align}
e_{ij}(\lambda) e_{ij}(\mu) &= e_{ij}(\lambda+\mu) \\
\left[ e_{ij}(\lambda),e_{jk}(\mu) \right] &= e_{ik}(\lambda \mu) && \mbox{for } i \neq k\\
\left[ e_{ij}(\lambda),e_{kl}(\mu) \right] &= \mathbf{1}          && \mbox{for } i \neq l, j \neq k\\
\end{align}$$

The Steinberg  group  is  the  universal  central extension  of the  special  linear  group over  $R$; $Sl_n(R)$.

Is  there  a  description of the  Steinberg  group $St_n(Z)$, the  special linear  group over  the integers as a  lattice  in  some  lie  group,  and  some  covering  map  realizing  the   universal  central  extension  of $Sln(R)$ (  real  coefficients), which  restricts  to the integral universal  central  extension of  $Sln(Z)$ given by the  Steinberg  group ?

Answer (score 6):

For $n\ge 3$ the Steinberg group $\text{St}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ is a lattice in the universal covering of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ (which has fundamental group the cyclic group of order 2).

To see that the inverse image of $\text{St}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ in the universal covering of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is indeed a non trivial central extension, essentially amounts to check that the image of $K_2(\mathbf{Z})$ in the topological $K_2$ or the reals is injective (but I guess that a suitable direct argument, for instance using an element of order 2, can work as well).

Comment: I mean "*of* the reals", sorry.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This started to be an answer, but my recollections were inaccurate.  It's essential here to distinguish carefully between what happens when $n=2$ (where life is much more complicated) and when $n \geq 3$ (where the situation stabilizes).   The definition of the Steinberg group differs in these situations.

Comment: @Jim: I respectfully disagree: $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is NOT simply connected for $n\geq 3$ (it is homotopy equivalent to $SO(n)$), so its universal cover is precisely of degree 2, and therefore the answer for the Steinberg group seems to be affirmative. 

Comment: @Alain: On further thought, I see that I was too hasty in my "answer", so I've edited most of it out.  Sorry for the confusion.